# Can you use mods in Civilization V multiplayer?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

When I load mods in Civilization V it only has option to start single player game. So is there any workaround or method for loading mods in multiplayer games? I am mostly interested in using some Interface only mods

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There was a [mod that made it so you could](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=390634), at least over LAN, but it's broken now. It's possible that this functionality will get added, but unlikely.